# Why NiFi GetJMSQueue not receiving messages?

Tags: jms, apache-nifi

I have an ActiveMQ JMS server and it works fine with JMS clients. Now I have to pass some information to NiFi processors via this server.

I added GetJMSQueue processor, set URL and Destination name properties, run processor... But it don't read messages. I really don't know if it connects to JMS server or not.

Any help, nifi-people?

Comment: Please add any logs or bulletins from your NiFi instance. Have you successfully connected with other JMS clients from the same machine that NiFi is running on?

Comment: tail the main nifi log file during execution for much more details.  You can also set the log level for individual processors (right click configure).   Update OP with details, and members will be able to better respond.